# Getting elements in Python list

Tags: python, list

I want to access the Name and the Teacher from the list. How do I access only two elements and add Name as key and Teacher as the value in dictionary?

```
list=['Name','Roll','opt_Subject','Grade','Teacher', 'Block', 'Symbol no', 'Bus_id', 'address', 'permanent address', 'Name','Roll','opt_Subject','Grade','Teacher', 'Block', 'Symbol no', 'Bus_id', 'address', 'permanent address',....nth]
```

Suppose in the list we have:

```
list=['Jon', '1','Eng','12','Harry', '2D', '129','2','USA', 'Ghana',
      'Jony', '12','Mth','122','Jack', '12D', '1429','27','Ghana', 'USA']
```

I want to add {'Jon':'Harry','Jony':'Jack'} and the above list has nth item but in same order.

Comment: Use indexing from the list to fetch the specific element

Comment: You've already posted the same question 3 hours ago... Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634162/printing-specific-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing specific list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634162/printing-specific-list)

Comment: No that's not the answer that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution

```py
keys = ['Name', 'Roll', 'opt_Subject', 'Grade', 'Teacher', 'Block', 'Symbol no', 'Bus_id', 'address',
        'permanent address', 'Name', 'Roll', 'opt_Subject', 'Grade', 'Teacher', 'Block', 'Symbol no', 'Bus_id',
        'address', 'permanent address']
values = ['Jon', '1', 'Eng', '12', 'Harry', '2D', '129', '2', 'USA', 'Ghana', 'Jony', '12', 'Mth', '122', 'Jack', '12D',
          '1429', '27', 'Ghana', 'USA']

result = {}
name = None
teacher = None
for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    if key == "Name":
        name = values[idx]
    if key == "Teacher":
        teacher = values[idx]
        result[name] = teacher

print(result)
```